# Function[] style name in questions' title disturb search

Tags: feature-request, search

Today I created a duplicated question, due to a simple standardization problem in function name. Some users use `function`, others use `function[]`.

If I look for `title:InputField`, I do not receive `InputField[]` as result. You can see the other functions like `Map`, `Flatten`, `Import` and so on, have the same problem. It's just look for `Import[]` to see.

Question1: Should we standardize these names in questions title's?

Question2: Can the search parser be improved to ignore `[]`?

Related meta question [(1)](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/973)

Comment: Re: Question 1, I'm in agreement with Istvan's answer (as were most people) and if you're editing a post, feel free to also remove the `[]` (unless the `[]` is necessary!) Re: Question 2, that's probably not going to happen since the search engine is common across all 100+ SE sites and tweaking it for one minor inconvenience on one site is unreasonable. Overall, re: searching for a question, I prefer to use Google with the `site:mathematica.stackexchange.com keywords` syntax. It's much better than SE's. I use the SE search when I need to search for a particular user's or closed posts and such.

Comment: @rm-rf I didn't know the search was global among all communities. I agree, to small improvement to change it.

Comment: I always remove `[]` from titles when I edit a question.